# Errors after installing flat remix gnome theme using terminal

Tags: command-line, gnome, themes, gnome-terminal

I am beginner in Ubuntu and I decided to try out flat remix gnome theme but I faced a very big problem while using the terminal commands which are as following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:daniruiz/flat-remix
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install flat-remix-gnome
```

But after applying the first two with no problems in the third command I start facing these codes every time I try installing any package:

```
Unpacking android-sdk-platform-tools-common (27.0.0+10~18.04.2) ...
Setting up android-liblog (1:8.1.0+r23-5~18.04) ...
Setting up flat-remix-gnome (20191117) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/flat-remix-gnome.postinst: 4: /var/lib/dpkg/info/flat-remix-gnome.postinst: make: not found
dpkg: error processing package flat-remix-gnome (--configure):
 installed flat-remix-gnome package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Setting up android-libboringssl (8.1.0+r23-2~18.04) ...
Setting up android-sdk-platform-tools-common (27.0.0+10~18.04.2) ...
Setting up android-libcrypto-utils (1:8.1.0+r23-5~18.04) ...
Setting up android-libbase (1:8.1.0+r23-5~18.04) ...
Setting up android-libcutils (1:8.1.0+r23-5~18.04) ...
Setting up android-libadb (1:8.1.0+r23-5~18.04) ...
Setting up adb (1:8.1.0+r23-5~18.04) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 flat-remix-gnome
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

and I tried to remove the package but it gives same error and I tried re-installing the package and this appear>>>

```
moutasim@moutasim-Aspire-A515-51G:~$ sudo apt-get install flat-remix-gnome
[sudo] password for moutasim: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
flat-remix-gnome is already the newest version (20191117).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up flat-remix-gnome (20191117) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/flat-remix-gnome.postinst: 4: /var/lib/dpkg/info/flat-remix-gnome.postinst: make: not found
dpkg: error processing package flat-remix-gnome (--configure):
 installed flat-remix-gnome package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 flat-remix-gnome
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Please help guys cause this is my second time reinstalling Ubuntu please help

Comment: Adding PPA's yourself is not without  risk. Try whether "sudo apt install -f" fixes current issues with your packages. Not sure whether these adb and android packages are related to flat-remix. They could be the cause of the issues.

Comment: No Bro, I tried installing adb and many other packages with same problem and I tried "sudo apt install -f" nothing changed

Comment: Revise your question then. The cause of your broken packages then may not be flat remix. You will have to repair your packaging system first.

Comment: + I tried synaptic package manager and didn't show any broken package

Comment: I tried toooooo many commands that I found in many web-pages and I get the same problem from the same package  https://pastebin.com/dp4pZGfU

Comment: Still don't believe you have broken packages? Try this guide to fix broken packages. Fixing package problems can be difficult. Are you sure the PPA you added is suited for your Ubuntu version? A wrong PPA can be the cause of breakage.

Comment: Yeah I searched for this and found this as half installed package problem, but usually I am totally unable to insert any codes that complete its procedure without the same problems and I cant remove the flat-remix-gnome package and I wasn't having the dpkg and cant install it now

Comment: If yo do not have the dpkg, then you messed up badly with your system. It will then be a reinstall, after which you will be more careful and stick to supported actions and supported software.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem

Into file `/var/lib/dpkg/info/flat-remix-gnome.postinst` has a command `make` and package is not installed: `make: not found`

I started Ubuntu with recovery mode and installed the package `make`, after reboot this problem has been solved